# The necessity of localVue to include components in Jest

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js, vue-test-utils

Do we really need to use localVue then insert the components to proceed testing with pages or views that are using other components? Is there an option where we do not need to do this then just focus with the expect and received instead? I am just starting with test scripting on VueJS/NuxtJS and the process for inserting components in localVue looks like it can be troublesome in the long run.

I already tried using global components and just manually declaring the components on my application development but still when I run in `npm run test` in my nuxtjs application it still can not find the component unless I use `localVue`

Comment: *Is there an option where we do not need to do this then just focus with the expect and received instead?* - yes, you describe black-box functional testing. It's orthogonal to unit testing.

Comment: I am talking about in a Vue Jest coding perspective not the concept. My question mainly revolves on the LocalVue

Comment: localVue allows to not overuse module mocking with `jest.mock`, otherwise you'll have to constantly mock Vue files that interfere with currently tested unit. It's either one or another if it's unit test. I referred to *focus with the expect and received instead*, this part is really about the concept, if you don't care about unit isolation and focus on expectations then it's e2e test.

Comment: When you say this: `focus with the expect and received instead`. Do you refer to test via each components in a small scale?

Comment: This includes testing at small scale. This approach is still labeled as integration/functional/e2e testing, depending on who you ask because the terminology is loose. It doesn't matter much how it's called but what this means in practice. If something breaks in a test where you didn't mock anything you may spend hours figuring out which part failed because you test the thing in whole even if you focus on a component. It's ok to have this kind of tests but they don't substitute fine-grained unit tests with less moving parts (that's what localVue does). If you're new to testing keep that in mind

Comment: Ok I will keep that in mind. So is there a way for me to not use `localVue` and include components manually on my test script when I want to do automated testing on a particular page with components?

Comment: Yes, there is. Use `jest.mock` on every module that causes undesirable side effects, including component modules. Use `jest.resetModules` or `jest.isolateModules` for each test to fully reset application state and prevent test cross-contamination. This way is more verbose and unnecessarily complicated so this is the reason why localVue is popular in Vue testing.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet?